# sizeWithFont:lineBreakMode Is Deprecated

Tags: ios, objective-c, deprecated

I am getting an error saying sizeWithFont:lineBreakMode Is Deprecated. Any Suggestions?

```
CGSize userButtonSize = [self.userButton.titleLabel.text 
sizeWithFont:self.userButton.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:constrainSize 
lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
```

Comment: What are you trying to do by using this method?

Comment: Look at the documentation for the deprecated method. It tells you what to use instead.

Answer (score 1):

The docs say to use `NSString`s [`boundingRectWithSize:options:attributes:context:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSAttributedString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSAttributedString/boundingRectWithSize%3aoptions%3acontext%3a).

```
- (CGRect)boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options
attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes context:(NSStringDrawingContext *)context
```

It returns a `CGRect`:

> Calculates and returns the bounding rect for the receiver drawn using the given options and display characteristics, within the specified rectangle in the current graphics context.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` because it is deprecated in ios6 or later version.

```
CGSize userButtonSize = [self.userButton.titleLabel.text 
sizeWithFont:self.userButton.titleLabel.font constrainedToSize:constrainSize 
lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail];
```